# AWS configure healthcheck EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a load balancer (LB) and an EC2 instance on AWS. My LB has my domain name associated and supports HTTP and HTTPS connections. It has a health-check configured to an endpoint on my EC2 instance (it's running node).

When trying to hit an endpoint via my domain name, the LB doesn't route traffic to my EC2 because it doesn't see it as a healthy instance. I can hit the endpoint directly with the IP address instead. What sort of response do I need to configure so that my EC2 can be recognized as healthy?

Edit: Using an application load balancer.

Edit 2: Health check configuration.

- Protocol: HTTPS
- Path : /callback
- Port : 443
- Healthy threshold : 5
- Unhealthy threshold : 2
- Timeout : 5
- Interval : 30
- Success codes : 200

Comment: Is the EC2 instance in one of the load balancer's configured AZs? Edit your question with the load balancer type (CLB, ALB, NLB), health check configuration and listener configuration.

Comment: Thanks, just added that I'm using an ALB

Comment: Please add all the information that I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: with the application LB, all that is needed is a 200-level status code from a designated url. This means that you cannot return a simple text response like "Hello World" when they send their health check request.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a path on the EC2 instance - you do NOT need to provide anything in DNS. It should look something like:

- Protocol:HTTP
- Port: 80
- Path: / (or any valid URL on your host that's
  a good example of your page working)

No DNS names need to be in there, remember - the ELB already knows which server(s) it's checking against, it just needs to know what to check on that server. Also make sure your security groups allow the ELB to talk to the server on the required ports.